# C++ Ошибки c cout в case

Tags: c++, вывод, switch, case

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int n, a, b;

    std::cin>>n;

    a=n%10;

    b=(n+8)%12;

    switch(a)
    {
    case 0,1:cout<<"White\n";break;
    case 2,3:cout<<"Black\n";break;
    case 4,5:cout<<"Green\n";break;
    case 6,7:cout<<"Red\n";break;
    case 8,9:cout<<"Yellow\n";break;

    }
    switch(b)
    {
    case 0:cout<<"Крыса\n";break;
    case 1:cout<<"Корова\n";break;
    case 2:cout<<"Тигр\n";break;
    case 3:cout<<"Заец\n";break;
    case 4:cout<<"Дракон\n";break;
    case 5:cout<<"Змеи\n";break;
    case 6:cout<<"Лошади\n";break;
    case 7:cout<<"Овца\n";break;
    case 8:cout<<"Обезьяна\n";break;
    case 9:cout<<"Курица\n";break;
    case 10:cout<<"Собака\n";break;
    case 11:cout<<"Свинья\n";break;

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: и какая ошибка?

Comment: @Naumov рискну предположить, что cout is not declared in this scope :)

Comment: Ошибку выбивает в каждом cout  в первом switch+ первый cout во втором

Answer (score 2):

Или добавьте

```
using namespace std;
```

или

```
using std::cout;
```

или к замените каждый `cout` на `std::cout`...

Comment: Попробовал, ничего не изменилось: 10:11: error: expected ':' before ',' token
10:11: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token

Comment: А это уже не с `cout` связано, а с `case` :) - см. ответ @yrHeTaTeJlb

Comment: теперь :
 3:1: error: expected initializer before 'using'
4:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Comment: @Вова http://ideone.com/uA1nnC

Answer (score 2):

1) `std::cout`
2) Вместо

```
case 1, 2:  
    cout << "smth";
    break;
```

нужно писать

```
case 1:
case 2:
    cout << "smth";
    break;
```

Comment: А кстати, забавно, что эти case'ы VC++ компилирует на ура, воспринимая, похоже, как составной оператор...

Comment: #include <iostream>
int main()
теперь ошибка в *:
using std::cout; *
{*
3:1: error: expected initializer before 'using'
4:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Comment: @Harry: Это, кстати, целая тема. Начиная с С++11, С++ разрешает использование оператора `,` в константных выражениях. То есть  оператора `,` может использоваться для формирования значений в метках case. Другое дело, что грамматика константного выражения требует скобок: т.е. `case (1, 2):` разрешено в C++11 (но не в C++03). С этой точки зрения VC++ в данном случае просто "забыл" потребовать наличия скобок.

Comment: @AnT Повозился с ним немного - он согласен на запятую, но лолько если перед ней - `constexpr`, так что чего-то типа отладочного вывода туда не воткнуть.

Comment: @Harry: Да, общие требования, накладываемые на операнды константного выражения, распространяются на оба операнда `,`.

Comment: @AnT Честно говоря, тогда не видно особой ценности этой возможности... А вообще спасибо, не знал. P.S. Однако в какие дебри иногда заводит простейшая ошибка :)

Comment: @Harry: Вот как раз об этом: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324573/why-was-the-restriction-on-the-comma-operator-being-in-a-constant-expression-rem Т.е. тут дело скорее не в ценности, а в том, что запрет на использование `,` в константных выражениях был фактически ничем не обоснован - его на автомате притащили из С, (да и там тоже не было особого обоснования). Вот его и решили отменить. А применения для него вполне можно наскрести.

Comment: @Вова, вот http://cpp.sh/8yo3k, сравните со своим кодом, поищите отличия